# How to handle dynamic number of items in with statement?

Tags: python, with-statement

Is there a nice way to replicate the following code to use a single `with` statement:

```
thing1 = Thing()
if two_things: 
    thing2 = Thing()

do_stuff(thing1)

if two_things:
    do_stuff(thing2)

thing1.close()
if two_things: 
    thing2.close()
```

I can use 2 separate with clauses, but this is pretty bad if a lot of the code is shared between the two cases.

```
if two_things:
    with Thing() as thing1, Thing() as thing2:
        do_stuff(thing1)
        do_stuff(thing2)

else: 
    with Thing() as thing:
        do_stuff(thing1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

["Supporting a variable number of context managers"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#supporting-a-variable-number-of-context-managers)

> The primary use case for `ExitStack` is the one given in the class documentation: supporting a variable number of context managers and other cleanup operations in a single `with` statement. The variability may come from the number of context managers needed being driven by user input (such as opening a user specified collection of files), or from some of the context managers being optional:
>
> ```
> with ExitStack() as stack:
>     for resource in resources:
>         stack.enter_context(resource)
>     if need_special_resource():
>         special = acquire_special_resource()
>         stack.callback(release_special_resource, special)
>     # Perform operations that use the acquired resources
> ```